# Can we use Semantic UI and Foundation at the same time?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, semantic-ui

Semantic UI is awesome but it is not really helpful for setting up a responsive/mobile-ready site architecture. Is it possible to use Foundation UI along with Semantic UI in the same project? I love the breadth of widgets available in Semantic (not to mention the dead-simple syntax), but I think I'd need to use Foundation's mobile/desktop grid capabilities.

So Foundation for frame (and maybe typography), Semantic UI for elements/widgets? Possible? Highly unrecommended?

(preemptive note: there seems to be a lot of overlap in capabilities between Foundation and Twitter Bootstrap and though I like Bootstrap too, Foundation seems broader in functionality without losing anything so that's why the specific Foundation-Semantic comparo)

Comment: I believe these days, the grid provided by Sementic UI is just as good?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question is answered in the Foundation FAQ (question #8, "Can I use just the grid?"): yes.